# why error occur when write csv in the file?

Tags: python, csv, module

Why give this error while writing to csv file ???
When I user csv.writer at that time code run perfectly but can not get header give me some suggestion and solution for this

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'**

```
import random
import csv

BloodGroup = ['A+', 'A-', 'B+', 'B-', 'O+', 'O-', 'AB+', 'AB-']
City = ['Ahmedabad', 'Gandhinagar', 'Vadodara', 'Rajkot', 'Surat']
Month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
ForWhat = ['anemia','cancer','hemophilia','kidney disease','liver disease','severe infection','sickle cell disease','thrombocytopenia']

bloodgroup = random.choice(BloodGroup)

city = random.choice(City)

if city == 'Ahmedabad':
    area = random.choice(['Gota', 'Maninagar', 'Bopal', 'Satellite', 'Bodakdev', 'Thaltej', 'Chandkheda', 'Prahlad Nagar', 'SG Highway'])
elif city == 'Gandhinagar':
    area = random.choice(['Sargaasan', 'Urjanagar', 'Kudasan', 'Zundal', 'Raysan', 'Shantigram'])
elif city == 'Vadodara':
    area = random.choice(['Alkapuri', 'Akota', 'Fatehgunj', 'Waghodia'])
elif city == 'Rajkot':
    area = random.choice(['Mota Mava', 'Kalawad', 'Bhakti Nagar', 'Madhapar'])
else:
    area = random.choice(['Sayan', 'Ghod Dod', 'Pal', 'Vesu'])


bloodquantity = random.randint(0,4)

month = random.choice(Month)

year = random.randint(2015, 2019)

forwhat = random.choice(ForWhat)

personcount = random.randint(0,10)

print(f'{bloodgroup} {city} {area} {bloodquantity} {month} {year} {forwhat} {personcount}')
data = [bloodgroup, city, area, bloodquantity, month, year, forwhat, personcount]
print('Data:',data)

with open('BloodBankDataSet.csv', 'w') as new_file:

    fieldname = ['Bloodgroup', 'City', 'Area', 'Bloodquantity', 'Month', 'Year', 'ForWhat', 'PersonCount']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames= fieldname)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DictWriter` expects a dictionary as the parameter and you're passing a list.

Consider using this:

```py
csv_writer.writerow({k: v for k,v in zip(fieldname, data)})
```